Uncooperative PhD Labmate
I'm a 2nd-year PhD student at a university in the US. I am experiencing issues with a labmate I was supposed to collaborate with. Our research is highly experimental, though our topics are different. While my labmate has a much better theoretical understanding of his research topic, I have more experience on the experimental side since I joined the lab a year before him.
Although our advisor likes both of us, he prioritizes my labmate's research project over mine because most of the funding comes from his project, and our lab has more achievements from his project due to previous publication records by other members. I used to respect my labmate a lot and wanted to learn from him until my advisor asked me to collaborate with him on the experimental part of his project to speed up the process.
My advisor left for a summer trip, and suddenly, my labmate started to ghost me and began working on the experimental work all on his own. I tried reaching out to him, but he was unresponsive, which led to a deterioration of my relationship with him. The project had three phases. Since I had more experience, we could have finished all three phases in two months. However, due to his ego, he alone worked on the first step, which I already completed in the first two weeks. I asked him to share and divide the work, but he didn't listen to me. In fact, after he finished the first step, I could have helped him complete the second step in one week. However, he ghosted me again and worked on the second step for more than a month. When I asked him about it, he got angry and said he was not seeking cooperation.
I was extremely saddened by this situation because I am the one who trained him on a major part of the experimental work. Most of the equipment to be used in the experimental work is also optimized by me.
I absolutely don't know what to do in this case. My project is progressing slowly as it's a completely new topic for our lab, and the only way I can get some publications is by collaborating with him (I don't want to be the first author either since it's his project). But he has made sure that I don't get to play any part in this process. Should I talk to my advisor about it, or should I switch to another research lab that focuses more on my topic?

I hope that when your advisor asked you to collaborate with this lab-mate, he told the lab-mate about it.

why don't you just start cc-ing your mentor on emails to this colleague and see what happens??


Should I talk to my advisor about it?

Yes, definitely. In fact, it sounds like 6+ weeks have already passed; you should have looped in your advisor much earlier. The cleanest way to do this would have been to cc the advisor on the e-mails to your lab-mate when you initially observed that they were declining your offer to collaborate. You didn't do anything wrong, so there was no reason not to inform your advisor that you were blocked due to something outside of your control.
At this point, enough time has passed that your position is not nearly as strong. 6+ weeks have been wasted, which is of course bad. And the other student has been making progress without you, so your advisor has fewer options for fixing this than they would have had if you had informed them promptly. But even so, telling your advisor now is the right (indeed, only) thing to do. The longer you wait, the worse it will get. Don’t be too nervous; although it would have been better to have communicated with your advisor earlier, a reasonable advisor will understand that you were unsure of your footing here.

should I switch to another research lab that focuses more on my topic?

Dealing with unreasonable and unfriendly personalities is unfortunately a major part of research. If you switch labs every time something like this happens, you will never make progress. That said, after you meet with your advisor, you can assess your options. A reasonable advisor would either find an alternative path for you, or force the other student to engage with you. If your advisor doesn't do either of these, then that's a much better reason to switch labs.

Yes, definitely. And I think all of cooperations like experiment assignment should be instructed by your advisor, not you. It is because you and your labmate are at the flat level. In theory he does not need to report the project stage to you. He may even suspect you want to 'steal' his project by doing some experiments.
